# Does Facebook respect your "except" list if those people are in "friends of tagged"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

If I post something on Facebook I can see in the privacy settings, I can make it visible to all of my friends and I can also choose "except" and list any individual people to not be included.

I am trying to understand how this behaves if there is a person tagged in the post and I include "Friends of Tagged" in the privacy scope.

So for example:

- I put a post and I tag "Joe".
- I set the privacy settings to "All Friends except Bill" **and** "Friends of Tagged"

If Bill is a friend of Joe's, will he see the post?  If yes, is there anyway to not have him able to see that besides removing "Friends of Tagged"?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, post would be invisible for Bill. Because you have post this and you have exclude him for seeing this post.

Basically, when you put someone in 'except' list, they can only see your public posts. Posts with any other privacy setting would be invisible for them.